# Yet another "unrecognized selector sent to instance" issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, sigabrt

I have just commenced the Apple "Your First iPhone App' tutorial and encountered a problem when attempting to run the app in the simulator.

I can enter my name and selecting the Done button makes the keyboard disappear, however I get an error once I press the Hello button. The log from Xcode reads;

```
2012-10-27 00:24:17.044 Hello World 2[955:c07] -[HelloWorldViewController changegreeting:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x897c1a0
2012-10-27 00:24:17.047 Hello World 2[955:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HelloWorldViewController changegreeting:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x897c1a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c8e012 0x10cbe7e 0x1d194bd 0x1c7dbbc 0x1c7d94e 0x10df705 0x16920 0x168b8 0xd7671 0xd7bcf 0xd6d38 0x4633f 0x46552 0x243aa 0x15cf8 0x1be9df9 0x1be9ad0 0x1c03bf5 0x1c03962 0x1c34bb6 0x1c33f44 0x1c33e1b 0x1be87e3 0x1be8668 0x1365c 0x263d 0x2565 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Can anyone help? I've gone over the project twice and get the same error each time I run it.

Comment: Need code. Mmmmm... code. Lovely scrumptious code.

Comment: Objective-C methods (and C++ and C functions) are case-sensitive, so `changegreeting:` looks suspiciously like a typo.

Comment: can u check in ur `HelloWorldViewController` is there any method naming `changegreeting` & does it requires a parameter..?

Comment: @trojanfoe thank you!! it was the changegreeting: misspelt. Works perfectly now.

Comment: that message comes typically when you are trying to use a method that does not exist, just check to see if the object you are dealing with really has that method. without code that is about as much as one can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the console log:

```
[HelloWorldViewController changegreeting:]
```

it seems you are calling a `changegreeting:` method on an instance of `HelloWorldViewController`, but the method is not found, so the call fails.

Now this can come down to 2 things:

1. you sent the message to the wrong object;
2. the method signature does not correspond to the way you are calling it: either the method name is different (`changeGreeting:`?) or it does not take an argument...

Hope this helps.